# How to create a multistep verification If statement?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the a userform:
[image]

I have several message boxes that make sure all necessary fields are completed/selected.

Example:

If CheckBox4 is Selected -> Is Number Box 4 or Text Box 4 selected? -> If not, there's a MsgBox warning.

If CheckBox4 is Selected -> is Weight Box 4 field empty? -> If yes, there's a MsgBox warning.

If Number box 4 is selected -> Is Normalization Box 4 selected? -> If not, there's a MsgBox warning.

Example code of one of these warnings:

```
' Make sure if additional metrics are selected : number or text is selected

If CheckBox1 = True And (NumBox1 = False And TxtBox1 = False) Then
    MsgBox ("Please define if the metric is numerical or text.")
    Exit Sub
End If

If CheckBox2 = True And (NumBox2 = False And TxtBox2 = False) Then
    MsgBox ("Please define if the metric is numerical or text.")
    Exit Sub
End If

'(...)
```

It works but it's a lot of code.
I'd like to compile all these "warnings" into a single MsgBox.

**Additional info:**

CheckBox1 / NumBox1 / TxtBox1 / NorBox1 / WBox1

CheckBox2 / NumBox2 / TxtBox2 / NorBox2 / WBox2

etc.

These are the names attributed to each control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone who thinks he's still new to VBA i'd say you're getting along quite well already!

I didn't test my code below, but I'd go with `.Controls("button/txtbox" & i)` to put it into one code.

```
For i = 1 to 4 '1 and 4 represent the start and end if you have 20 checkboxes change 4 to 20. If the first number used is checkbox5, change 1 to 5 etc.
    With Userform1
        If .Controls("CheckBox" & i) = True And .Controls("NumBox" & i) = False And .Controls("TxtBox" & i) = False Then
            MsgBox ("Please define if the metric is numerical or text.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
Next
```

This will loop all the requirements, if something is False (so if a checkbox is not checked) no MsgBox should appear. But for all the checked boxes and the other criteria are false it should bring up the MsgBox like before and exit the sub.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words! I'm not sure I understood correctly, but the code you gave me would one verify a if the number/text box was selected. Right?

Comment: Yes. As in my examply (i = 1 to 4) it will Loop the following: > Checkbox1 / Numbox1 / Textbox1. If one of those meets all the cirteria it will show the MsgBox and exit, if not it will go on to the next. Checkbox2 / Numbox2 etc etc

Comment: I think may have not explained myself well. For all the "rows", I need to check:
1. If Text or Num Box is selected.
2. If Num Box is selected: Is Normalization selected?
3. If all the selected checkboxes have weights.

Comment: Something is not clear to me perhaps, but what i've shown you above should do exactly that. If each line of checkbox/numbox/textbox has a upgoing number: 1, 2, 3, 4 a new number for each 'row'. a loop like this shoud do it. It depends on when you want to perform this "check", this code assumes you want to check all rows at the same time when pressing a button for example. If you want to perform the check when you check the corresponding checkbox, you have to code each 'row' seperatly and in that case i'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm changing it a bit, but the overall idea works. Thanks! :)